# Create license key with IMEI for mobile

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have a question and I can't find clear answers and solutions.

I want to create a license key system to activate my application. The phones on which the application will be installed cannot be connected to the internet. Moreover, these are sometimes reinitialized and it is, therefore, necessary to install the application again.

I have never done a licensing system so any improvement is welcome. With these constraints, I thought to make sure that the user transmits his IMEI.

I generate a license key according to the IMEI. When the user enters the license key I compare if the license key matches the IMEI of the phone.

The problem is that since the versions of Android 10 and higher, it is no longer possible to recover an IMEI. Instead, we can retrieve a UUID(Unique identifier). But this can change if we reset the phone if I understand correctly. So this is not good because it will make my license invalid.

I don't see how to do it

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to get a unique identifier for either ios or Android any more.  You'll have to embrace the idea that people can reinstall their phone software anywhere.

Comment: I am working with flutter and I can get a unique ID number ... I don't understand.  My problem is precisely according to my research we no longer have access to the IMEI since android 10. So if I reset the phone the unique identifier changes and the paid license key is no longer valid...

Comment: Right... you can no longer get a guaranteed persistent unique identifier.

Comment: If it's not possible with IMEI or UUID, can I use MAC adress for realize my system ?

Comment: ios 14 scrambles the mac address on each new wifi connect!

Comment: Thanks for the information but what does this imply? My system uses the base mac address to identify the phone when the application starts. Is there a number that I can access that allows me to do my system? For now I have finished doing what I want with the MAC address.

Comment: No, that is deliberately what they are moving away from, and for many good reasons.  Instead, ensure the user logs in to establish a continuation of a previous conversation.

Comment: Without internet connection this is therefore impossible.These are special company phones that do not have to be connected.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

As others contributors have already said, it's getting harder and harder to uniquely identify a device. This seems to be largely due to applications abusing device identity to track user behavior and otherwise abuse personal information.

This does make life hard for people like you who are simply trying to protect their work.

Google does offer an alternative, but it takes a little shift in thinking.
Instead of thinking of your software being allowed to operate on a device (requiring some unique identification), think of it as the *licensed user* is allowed to use your software.

Google provides an API for this; [Google Play Licensing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing). Essentially you use Google play services to test *this* user's eligibility to use your software (through a remote api call to Google). There are quite a few control mechanisms and options available and although it takes a little time to understand and set up, as long as you are distributing through the Google play store, it simplifies licensing over all, and shouldn't suddenly stop working because IMEIs (or any other identifiable information) aren't available. It's also a bit harder to hack.

Hope this helps, best of luck :-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer  But I can't use Api call because phones are not connected to internet and my application is sensitive and cannot be distributed on google play store.  This problem does not seem to have a solution.

Comment: Hmm. Well, it gets much more complicated but you could look into device fingerprinting (as much information about the physical device as you can find to form a checksum/hash code; eg name of network carrier, device model and name, time of app instalation to millisecond etc)
 or using information that only a user would know (and would not want to give away) to create some kind of activation code, of course this would not persist across installations and a new installation requires a new code.

Comment: Another approach (similar) would be to have the user apply for an installation code using personal information they would not want to give away.
The installation code would be "activated" (maybe decoded) by re-entering the same information on the device. You would probably salt the code with the app install time (millisecond accuracy) to prevent re-use. Then the user could only give away the code if they also give the personal information to unlock it.. much less likely.
There are naturally some big information privacy issues with this, so I'd think carefully. Not necessarily a good idea.

Comment: What if I use the MAC address instead of the IMEI. My problem is actually having a unique number to identify the device that doesn't change when I reset the phone or the app. IMEI is no longer accessible, UUID is not reliable but the MAC address would be a good compromise? It's not perfect but it's the only solution I found

Comment: Unfortunately even the MAC address isn't stable any more. Android now provides "random" MAC addresses for untrusted networks specifically to prevent user tracking and privacy abuse.
I haven't found any simple way of creating an ID that will survive an app reinstall/clear data and doesn't require network access in some way.

Comment: I sympathize with your problem and have actually had the same problem (although in different ways) which led me to look at all kinds of things including "piggy backing"  on google cloud backup in various ways. Google is working hard to strengthen user privacy from third parties, that includes tracking users which unfortunately means they are deliberately blocking device identification.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that the MAC addresses were not stable either ... Permanent offline application activation is therefore no longer possible. If the MAC address changes so much take the UUID and make a license change when a device is reset ... It's a shame not to be able to support this kind of system anymore.